# Disable web access (HTTP) for a DNS record

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, a-record, srv-record

I have a DNS record (A record) that points to a server that have TeamSpeak3 server and a web server.

I'd like to disable web access to the record but keep the TeamSpeak3 access.

NOTE: I don't own the server and I don't have access to it, so I can't setup Apache VirtualHosts or similar.

I tried to create a `SRV` record like `_http._tcp.example.com` but it didn't work.

Comment: Why do you care about web traffic going to that server if you don't own the server?

Answer (score 3):

The DNS record is not protocol aware. An `A` record  only points to IPv4 address and you cannot control which client is used (web browser, teamspeak, mail). If corresponding port for given service is open, clients can connect to the server.

There is no way how to block web access on DNS level

SRV record still needs to point to A (or AAAA) record, so you only move problem to one level above, but it still persist

Comment: This is not what the question is about. It is about web browsers not using DNS SRV as they should.